# Web scraping price and names of mobiles?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a new learner of python and i am trying to scrape the name and price of particular mobiles form flipkart.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

name=[]
price=[]
rating=[]


url="https://www.flipkart.com/search?sid=tyy%2C4io&otracker=CLP_Filters&p%5B%5D=facets.ram%255B%255D%3D4%2BGB&p%5B%5D=facets.rating%255B%255D%3D4%25E2%2598%2585%2B%2526%2Babove"

results=requests.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(results.text,"html.parser")

soup.prettify()

details=soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"bhgxx2 col-12-12"})

for mobiles in details:
    mob_name=mobiles.find("div",attrs={"class":"_3wU53n"})
    name.append(mob_name.text)
    print(name)
```

Output:

File "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/mobile scrapping.py", line 30, in 
name.append(mob_name.text)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: In your title it is mobile while in your post it is hotel .Moreover your link is of flipkart and you mentioned goibibo. Please modify it and it is text not txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Check this out

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://www.flipkart.com/search?sid=tyy%2C4io&otracker=CLP_Filters&p%5B%5D=facets.ram%255B%255D%3D4%2BGB&p%5B%5D=facets.rating%255B%255D%3D4%25E2%2598%2585%2B%2526%2Babove"
results=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(results.text,"html.parser")
mobiles=[]
rates=[]
details=soup.findAll("div",attrs={"class":"_3wU53n"})
for i in details:
    mobiles.append(i.text)
prices=soup.findAll("div",attrs={"class":"_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK"})
for j in prices:
    rates.append(j.text)
final=[[x,y] for x,y in zip(mobiles,rates)]
print(final)
```

Output: ['Realme Narzo 10A (So White, 64 GB)', '₹9,999'], ['Realme Narzo 10 (That Blue, 128 GB)', '₹11,999']]